# Connecting to an API at azurewebsites.net to download a JSON file

Tags: python, json, azure, swagger

I need to connect an API on azurewebsites using Python to download a JSON file automatically.
I can access the website and download a JSON file manually.
I tried to connect using:

```
url = 'https://myplatformconnectiot.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html'

r = requests.get(url, headers={"Authentication": " application/json"},cookies={},auth=('user@example.com', 'password'),)

r.json()
```

Do you know how to download a JSON file in azurewebsites using Python?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [kudu console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu#access-kudu-for-your-app) url to a get particular file download from a web app.
By using the below python code you can download the file form the web app

```
import  json
import  requests
url  =  'https://<webappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/wwwroot/css/site.css'
r  =  requests.get(url,auth=('username','urlpassword'))

with  open(r'C:\Users\name.json','wb')  as  f:

f.write(r.content)
```

username & password will be from publish profile credentials file of a web app. you can get the publish profile credentials from portal as shown in below image
[image]

Kudu is the engine behind a number of features in [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview) related to source control based deployment, and other deployment methods like Dropbox and OneDrive sync.

for more information about [kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) you can refer the below document